# How does the Index get decremented after reaching the length of my array?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, backtracking

I am new to Backtracking, and I was solving 78. Subsets on Leetcode. After, debugging this solution I found that when we reach let's say index = 3 in array like [1, 2, 3] we decrement it again when we hit return statment in the if condition. However, I don't really understand how did this happen ?

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        subset = []
        def dfs(index):
            if(index >= len(nums)):
                res.append(subset.copy())
                return
            
            subset.append(nums[index])
            dfs(index + 1)

            subset.pop()
            dfs(index + 1)
        dfs(0)
        return res
```

and how we jump from appending the nums[index] in the subset to poping the numbers from it ?
I don't really grasb it even after debugging it

**The Question
**
78. Subsets

Given an integer array nums of unique elements, return all possible subsets

The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. Return the solution in any order.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output: [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key in understanding the backtracking to "previous" index values, is that each execution of `dfs` has its **own** `index` name. This name is not to be confused with the `index` of the *caller*. Although both the caller and the "callee" use the same name, these can have different values. Note how the caller passes `index + 1` to the recursive call, but does not really *update* its own `index`; it merely tells the called function to initialise their `index` with one more.

This means that when that recursive call finishes, their `index` reaches its end-of-life, and the caller continues with its own `index`, which didn't change. This may give the *impression* that a value is being decreased, but that is not actually what happens.

Incidentally, the local `index` represents the current *depth* of the recursion.